# ralink rt3290 driver for ubuntu mate 18.04 not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04

I have an HP Pavilion laptop and have just upgraded from Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to 18.04. After the upgrade my wireless does not work. It already had problems in 16.04 for which I had found a solution. This solution does not work in 18.04 and I have been unable to find any solution on the internet.

lspci shows this:`sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force`

How can I get my wireless connection working on 18.04? All help appreciated. And, obviously, I'd be happy to post more info if required.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and include your wireless script results to your question

Comment: The wireless info is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zKbBbyjpxd/